# How do I create a background in a container that is scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do something similar with the example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_parallax_percent) but I would like to know how to make it look more of like this sites layout [www.naturalbambootoothbrushes.com](http://www.naturalbambootoothbrushes.com) and i'm not too sure how to achieve this using html/css yet let alone with bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('img_parallax.jpg');

 /* Full height */
 height: 100%; 

/* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parallax, not just scrolling effect.

Comment: @guyboris I think your approach is not the right one, find below a detailed answer and a link to codepen that I believe will help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think is the same with w3Schools. if you put height from 100% to 50% or less and put navbar and content. Also if you put the `<div class="parallax" </div>` only in the top of the content and no from both side

I make a quick example to tell me if I don't understand something

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GACT5FVY1MVP

sorry for my bad English, I hope I helped u!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same result of the link you shared, you just need to place the text content **inside** the DIV that has the background, then make sure the background-attachment property is set to fixed, and the rest of the background CSS also needs to be tweaked so that the image covers all the space of the div that contains the text. You can integrate this CSS and HTML with your bootstrap theme easily. I have wrapped the text content in a div and added Flex to the div that has the background image, so that the text is centred vertically and horizontally.

Check the HTML on the codepen link.

```
.has-background  {
  background-image: url("https://ep00.epimg.net/elpais/imagenes/2019/12/20/album/1576841062_890975_1576842352_album_normal.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height:90vh;
  color:#fff;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 }
     .flex-item {
width:70%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/somestuff/pen/Exavwwe

Answer (score 0):

How this appears depends on the position of the **div** that has the background image.

If you want the parallax effect to appear after some elements of website, you put the background div after those elements.

If you want to show text on the image (as is shown on the website link that you added), just enter the text inside that **div with the background**.